# AtomicSwap instead of AtomicCompareAndSwap?

Tags: atomic-swap, compare-and-swap

I know that on MacOSX / PosiX systems, there is atomic-compare-and-swap for C/C++ code via g++.

However, I don't need the compare -- I just want to atomically swap two values. Is there an atomic swap operation available? [Everythign I can find is atomic_compare_and_swap ... and I just want to do the swap, without comparing].

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the "lock xchg" intel assembly instruction probably achieves what you want but i dont think there is a GCC wrapper function to make it portable.  Therefor your stuck using inline assembly(not portable) or using compare and swap and forcing the compare to be true(inneficient). Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

GCC does provide this operation on some processors, under the (confusingly named) `__sync_lock_test_and_set`. From the GCC documentation:

> ```
>  This builtin, as described by Intel, is not a traditional
>  test-and-set operation, but rather an atomic exchange operation.
>  It writes VALUE into `*PTR', and returns the previous contents of
>  `*PTR'.
>
>  Many targets have only minimal support for such locks, and do not
>  support a full exchange operation.  In this case, a target may
>  support reduced functionality here by which the _only_ valid value
>  to store is the immediate constant 1.  The exact value actually
>  stored in `*PTR' is implementation defined.
> ```

However the full swap operation is supported on x86-32 and x86-64, effectively providing the `lock xchg` wrapper you would otherwise need to write.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is. Here's the reference, btw:
http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/DriversKernelHardware/Reference/libkern_ref/OSAtomic_h/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/header/user_space_OSAtomic.h